# How do I allow user to select table column they want in Drupal View?

Tags: views

I am trying to create a Human Resources Portal for my organisation. 
I have to create a table via View to show all the list of staff of the organisation which is about 500 employees.
My major problem is that not all the column is needed at every situation, sometimes they need to create a table with only few columns at a time, so I need to expose the users (HR Dept) the columns so they can decide which one they need at a time. 
I have tried MediaTable module but that does not allow the user to hide columns themselves.
I need like a checkbox of columns to be selected.
Thank you

Comment: You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/flexible_views

Answer (score 2):

Give a look at [Views Dynamic Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dynamic_fields) module. I have used it in the past to create selectable table columns to display for views.

> The Views Dynamic Fields module provides a filter for use with Views
>   module. This filter allows the user to pick and choose which fields to
>   display for a rendered instance of a view for that user. This provides
>   a customized view instance for each user.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Users can dynamically choose the fields to view in their rendered view instance
> - Default fields to show when no filtering is applied, can be configured
> - Possible to always keep certain fields to display to the user
> - An exclusion mode to allow reverse selection of fields when there are too many
> - Great for creating and exporting reports from the view
> - Works great with Fields Embed Views module